# Can't call 32bit dll under 64bit windows

Tags: windows, 32bit-64bit, dllregistration

I try to create a COM object from my JS script like this:

```
function main() 
{
var MyApplication = new ActiveXObject("Base.Application");
}

main();
```

I am getting error: "Automation server can't create object". This error occurs on Windows 2003 64 bit. The dll is 32 bit and it works fine on 32 bit systems.

I've tried **both** versions of Regsvr32.exe on the 64 bit system and both versions told me that dll registered succesfully.

Unfortunatelly the error message does not tell me why it can not create object. The reason is unknown, it might be that it can't create object because it is still not registered or it might be something  totally different...

I've also add full permisions to this dll.

I don't know what else I can do, do you have any ideas?

**After edit**

Ok, I know that this DLL is registered under system (found it at the registry), so why I can't call any COB objects from it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because your process is 64 bits and you try to call in a 32 bit dll? (There are some tricks though, in this case like the one described [here](http://www.dnjonline.com/article.aspx?id=jun07_access3264)).